# how to check '/' and '</' present in input value in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input, file-io

```
ih=input('type here: ')
h='</'
if h not in ih:
    print('yrs')
if r'/' in ih or r'\\' in ih and h not in ih:
    print('its a file')
    open(ih,'r')
else:print('not found')
```

With this code i want to validate the input value like if  `/` or `\\` in the input value and `</` not in input value then it will print `its a file` but here the problem is when i input </something then the code prints `its a file` which i dont want so help me to get my desired output plz i am new to here to ask questions.

Comment: You can try using regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Put brackets around the `or` part of your condition, its short circuiting on the first or statement

```
if (r'/' in ih or r'\\' in ih) and h not in ih:
```